Excel contains long paragraph formatted (spaces, tabs, new lines, ..) how to show it in Power BI Dashboard with same format
Thank you for your support in advance.
I have an Excel source file column that contains long paragraph formatted (spaces, tabs, new lines, ..), my inquiry is how to show this paragraph in the Power BI Dashboard with the same format in Excel?

I would use the Custom Visual: HTML Content (lite)
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/coacervolimited1596856650797.htmlcontent_certified?tab=Overview
The "lite" version of this visual is preferred, as it is a certified Custom Visual. This means it will output correctly when report pages are exported as PDF or PowerPoint.
This visual usually "just works", without any tweaking of settings etc.
